# Is clair/jenkins plugin available?

Tags: security, jenkins, clair

Is there jenkins plugin available for clair for scanning vulnerabilities in Docker images?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no.

If you're looking to perform container security analysis as part of your Jenkins CI/CD, you could use [Anchore](https://anchore.com/) and the [anchore container scanner plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/anchore-container-scanner/) for Jenkins.